# Ajax/Json DataTables

Tags: php, json, ajax, datatables

I have 3 files, index.php, ajax.php, and scripts.js.

This is my ajax.php:

```
if ( $_GET['action'] == "newUserAccountsGrid" )
{

    try
    {

        $stmt = $DB_CONN->prepare("SELECT * FROM crm_users");
        $stmt->execute();
        $i=1;
        while ( $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) )
        {
            $obj[$i]['username']        = $rows->{'username'};
            $obj[$i]['firstname']       = $rows->{'firstname'};
            $obj[$i]['lastname']        = $rows->{'lastname'};
            $obj[$i]['user_email']      = $rows->{'user_email'};
            $obj[$i]['user_level']      = $rows->{'user_level'};
            $obj[$i]['user_role']       = $rows->{'user_role'};
            $obj[$i]['date_created']    = $rows->{'date_created'};
            $i++;
        }

    }
    catch( PDOException $e )
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    if ( is_array($obj) )
    {
        $arr['data'] = array_values($obj);
        $json = json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        echo $json;
    }

}
```

datatable javascript scripts.js :

```
$( "#tbl_useraccounts" ).dataTable({
    ajax: "ajax.php?action=newUserAccountsGrid",
    columns: [
        { "data": "username" },
        { "data": "firstname" },
        { "data": "lastname" },
        { "data": "user_email" },
        { "data": "user_level" },
        { "data": "user_role" },
        { "data": "date_created" },
    ],

    columnDefs: [{
        defaultContent: "-",
        targets: "_all"
    }]
});
```

Also index.php :

```
<table id="tbl_useraccounts" class="table table-striped table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="no-sort">Username</th>
            <th class="no-sort">First Name</th>
            <th class="no-sort">Last Name</th>
            <th class="no-sort">User Email</th>
            <th class="no-sort">User Level</th>
            <th class="no-sort">User Role</th>
            <th class="no-sort">Date Created</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>User Email</th>
            <th>User Level</th>
            <th>User Role</th>
            <th>Date Created</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Json is ok :

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "username": "test1",
            "firstname": "Test 1",
            "lastname": "Test 1",
            "user_email": "test1@test.com",
            "user_level": "1",
            "user_role": "Broker",
            "date_created": "2017-06-19 15:10:32"
        },
        {
            "username": "test2",
            "firstname": "Test 2",
            "lastname": "Test 2",
            "user_email": "test2@test.com",
            "user_level": "1",
            "user_role": "Consulent",
            "date_created": "2017-06-19 15:10:32"
        },
        {
            "username": "test3",
            "firstname": "Test 3",
            "lastname": "Test 3",
            "user_email": "test3@test.com",
            "user_level": "1",
            "user_role": "Consulent",
            "date_created": "2017-06-19 15:10:32"
        }
    ]
}
```

So everything executes fine, no errors, table renders the rows, **but no data is displayed**.
Thank you guys for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by "table renders the rows, but no data is displayed"?  You have a series of empty rows?

Comment: @EatPeanutButter Yes i have a sieries of empty rows.

Comment: @davidkonrad i have tried that, doesn't matter.

Comment: When you use the dev tools to inspect the rendered page, does the data actually get placed inside the rows?  (I.e., do you have some weird CSS rules hiding the text?)

Comment: @EatPeanutButter corresponding to the documentation : [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) this should work.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the client side code **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/937/** you do have disabled caching in the browser ...?

Comment: @davidkonrad nope i dont have disabled caching...